# Test planning, results, search, compare and reports

Tags: testing

I'm looking for a Tool to do

1. Test planning
2. Inserting test results
3. Searching previous tests and results
4. Comparing multiple test results
5. Making reports out of existing test
   data

The tests could be almost anything. For example testing performance of a specific software in a specific hardware. The point is that it would be possible to search earlier test procedures and results to be able to reproduce the test conditions. For example new results could be written using the same procedure only with different hardware.

This tool would be used to record test plans and results. The tools would NOT be used for executing the tests. The tool would act more as a database for developers to insert test plans and result, search existing tests and compare results.

Answer (score 2):

How about retrofitting an existing blog, wiki or CMS engine for doing this?

Say for example, in a wiki each wiki article could represent a test. You could have page templates set up, with required sections like "purpose", "scenario", "results".

Pick a system you're already familiar with, so you'll have something running quickly, use it for a while, see what customizations it needs. Once the list of hard-to-implement things gets bigger, you can look for a custom tool, and you'll have a solid list of requirements by then.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a test (case) management software. A good test management software lets you plan tests (and cases), record results and print reports/provide relevant metrics. Assigning tests to team members and email notifications similar to defect/bug tracking tools should also be included in a good tool. There are quite a few tools for this out there. A modern web-based test management app is our tool [TestRail](https://www.gurock.com/testrail), feel free to give it a try.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gurock.com](http://www.gurock.com/images/feature/testrail-screenshot-home-v2.png))</sub>